# Return value from command laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I am trying to access data in my laravel system, from nodejs, I want to do that using laravel command, so I'll run the command in nodejs and use the output of the command, my problem is the command is no return value, it just returns int value 0/1
so I need to get that data in order to use it in my node js code
this is my command in laravel

```
  public function handle()
    {     
        $router_id = $this->argument('router_id');
        $nas=NAS::withoutGlobalScope('company_id')->with('mikrotik')->where("id",$router_id)->first();
        if($nas)
        {
            $login= $nas->mikrotik->login;
            $password=$nas->mikrotik->password;
            $port=$nas->mikrotik->port;

            return    json_encode(['username'=>$login,'password'=>$password,'port'=>$port]);
        }
    }
```

how can I  get output from this command, or at least are there another way that I can do my work(I don't want API), because I need to change the code of the called API  address every time I install the system

Comment: It's probably a bit more secure to just hit your Laravel web API from Node. Otherwise you're having to access the shell directly from Node, which you need to be careful about.

Comment: thanks for reply , yes I know this , but  my problem is the command is return nothings  , how can I make that command to return value ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$this->line()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-output).

```php
public function handle()
{     
    $router_id = $this->argument('router_id');
    $nas = NAS::withoutGlobalScope('company_id')->with('mikrotik')->where("id",$router_id)->first();

    if($nas)
    {
        $login = $nas->mikrotik->login;
        $password = $nas->mikrotik->password;
        $port = $nas->mikrotik->port;

        $this->line(json_encode(['username'=>$login,'password'=>$password,'port'=>$port]));
        return;

    }
}
```